# How to include metadata in a template file?

Tags: ruby, metadata, yaml, erb, webby

I have a system that filters template files through erb.  Using convention over configuration, the output files get created in a file hierarchy that mirrors the input files.  Many of the files have the same names, and I was able to use the directories to differentiate them.

That plan worked until I needed to associate additional info with each file.  So I created a YAML file in each directory with the metadata.  Now I have both convention ***and*** configuration.  Yuck.

Then I learned [Webby](http://webby.rubyforge.org), and the way it includes a YAML metadata section at the top of each template file.  They look like this:

```
---
title: Baxter the Dog
filter: textile
---
All the best little blogs use Webby.
```

If I could implement a header like that, I could ditch my hierarchy and the separate YAML files.  The Webby implementation is very generic, implementing a new MetaFile class that separates the header from the "real text", but it seems more complicated than I need.

Putting the metadata in an erb comment seems good -- it will be automatically ignored by erb, but I'm not sure how to access the comment data.

```
<%#
title: Baxter the Dog
%>
```

Is there a way to access the erb comments?  Or maybe a different approach?  A lot of my templates do a bunch of erb stuff, but I could run erb in a separate step if it makes the rest easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about if you dump your content as YAML too. Presumably the metadata is simply a Hash dumped to YAML. You could just append the content as string in a second YAML document in the same file :-

```
---
title: Baxter the Dog
filter: textile
--- |
Content line 1
Content line 2
Content line 3
```

Dumping is as simple as :-

```
File.open('file.txt', 'w') do |output|
  YAML.dump(metadata, output)
  YAML.dump(content, output)
end
```

Loading is as simple as :-

```
File.open('file.txt') do |input|
  stream = YAML.load_stream(input)
  metadata, content = stream.documents
end
```

Note that the pipe character appears in the YAML [so that newlines in the content string are preserved](http://www.yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html#single_ending_newline).

Comment: I like this approach; nicer for human viewing than the erb comment.  Some of my content might already include yaml, but I think I'm safe if I escape any document separators?  \---